# bulk posting to wordpress via scripts

Tags: api, wordpress, import, bulk

In current project i need to make bulk posts to wordpress (from text files) and need to add dates of mine own choice .

What is best way to do it  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XML-RPC.  You can build a script that reads the text file, then makes an XML-RPC request to the WordPress server to create the post.  You'll need to have a valid username and password to make this work (and will need to enable XML-RPC on the WordPress site as well).

The API is fairly well-defined.  You make an XML-RPC call to `metaWeblog.newPost` and pass in the blog information, the post content, and your username and password.  WordPress does the rest.  You can also specify the date the post was/will be published as an optional field.

Further reading

- [XML-RPC Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) « WordPress Codex
- [WordPress XML-RPC MetaWeblog API](http://mindsharestrategy.com/wp-xmlrpc-blogger/) « My own documentation of the API
- [RFC: MetaWeblog API](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi) « Further documentation of the API

Comment: Your solution is good . also there is import options in WP so that can also be used ..

Comment: There are import options yes, but the files must be in specific formats for WordPress to import them.